# Retrieving rows from dynamoDB from Lambda based on primary key?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Below is the code of my Lambda function. I'm having trouble querying rows based on the timestamps. My plan is to get all the rows from 5 seconds before the current time to the current time in milliseconds. TimeMillis(Number) stores the current time in miiliseconds and it is the primary key and the range key is PhoneId(String). Please help me with the solution or is there any way to overcome the problem?

I'm not able to get the output, it is throwing error.

```
'use strict';

var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({
region: "us-east-1",
});
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {

var timemillis = new Date().getTime();
var timemillis1 = timemillis - 5000;

var params = {
    TableName: 'Readings',
    KeyConditionExpression:  "TimeMillis = :tm and TimeMillis BETWEEN :from AND :to",
    ExpressionAttributeValues:  {
        ":tm"   : "TimMillis",
        ":from" : timemillis1,
        ":to"   : timemillis
    }
};

docClient.query(params, function(err, data)   {
   if(err){
       callback(err, null);
   } 
   else{
       callback(null, data);
   }
});
};
```

Here is my DynamoDB table image.

[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting??

Comment: Error Shown is : `_"errorMessage": "KeyConditionExpressions must only contain one condition per key"_`

Comment: If I replace the above code with the following: `KeyConditionExpression: "TimeMillis BETWEEN :from AND :to",
        ExpressionAttributeValues:  {
            ":from" : timemillis1,
            ":to"   : timemillis
        }` .                                                                                                                             Error shown is: `**"errorMessage": "Query key condition not supported"**`

Comment: Is there any solution to use and get rows by using **BETWEEN** condition to the primary key, in this case **TimeMillis**, or Can you suggest any alternative solution if possible on how to overcome this situation?

Comment: I have added an answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple conditions inside a `KeyConditionExpression`. What you can do is use a `FilterExpression` with `KeyConditionExpression` to narrow down the result set.

Quoting from the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html),

> Use the KeyConditionExpression parameter to provide a specific value
>   for the partition key. The Query operation will return all of the
>   items from the table or index with that partition key value. You can
>   optionally narrow the scope of the Query operation by specifying a
>   sort key value and a comparison operator in KeyConditionExpression. To
>   further refine the Query results, you can optionally provide a
>   FilterExpression. A FilterExpression determines which items within the
>   results should be returned to you. All of the other results are
>   discarded.

Also for the test, only supported test for partition key is **equality**. Other conditions can be applied to sort key.

> ```
> partitionKeyName = :partitionkeyval AND sortKeyName = :sortkeyval
> ```

Another way is to create a GSI which support further querying. By the way, traditional RDBMS thinking would not work best with DynamoDB. You can read about best practices [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/BestPractices.html).